# Return value from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the return bool from the ajax call, but when I run the function and save to a variable but the only thing i get is undefined.

```
function check(number, id){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ai.php',
        data: {
            "func":"checkNumber",
            "id":id,
            "number":number
        },
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(jData) {
        return jData['idFound'];
    }).fail(function(jData) {
        console.log(jData['idFound']);
    });
}

var test = check(44444, 12);
console.log(test);
// true

// but i get an undefined value in the console.log
```

Comment: Try `console.log(jData.data['idFound']);`

Comment: Are you sure the property `idFound` is present in the result `jData`? Maybe you could provide more info about the result.

Comment: jData.data['idFound'] return a bool.

if i console.log(jData.data['idFound']) it will write the bool

Comment: You cannot receive synchronous result from asynchronous function. You only can call some callback which depends on result in `done` or `fail` part.

Comment: isn't it possible to return the jData.data['idFound'] value  from the function check ?

Comment: in .done write console.log(jData), if it's undefined the issue is in your PHP

Comment: if i do that i get the bool true.. but if I try to return it i get an undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Depend ur file **'ai.php'** is a format json? please check validate http://www.jsonlint.com

Confuse ur code data, its just 'post' and not 'get'.

You can try **getjson** or **ajax**, look a exemple:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.getJSON('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NkmG8_zBZ', function(json) {
  for (x=0; x<json.length; x++) {
          console.log('getjson>'+json[x].nome);
        }
 });

 $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NkmG8_zBZ',
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    for (x=0; x<json.length; x++) {
            console.log('ajax>'+json[x].cidade);
          }
  },
  error: function(err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
 });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without playing with the code more, this looks like an asynchronous issue to me.

This line calls the async function:

```
var test = check(44444, 12);
```

but logging the result immediately after will be `undefined` because you can't guarantee a return value unless you are within the 'done' callback function.

The default JQuery AJAX behavior is asynchronous, but if you truly need it to be synchronous, you can set the option explicitly, although it is not considered good practice:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    ...
});
```

Comment: If i return the value from the done I still get undefined... but it can console.log the value from 'done'

Comment: Did you try the suggestion made in the comments: `console.log(jData.data['idFound']);`

Comment: If I console.log(jData.data['idFound']); then it write the value  want to store in a variable

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you are saying. If you `console.log(jData.data['idFound']);` inside the `done` function, are you getting what you expect? If you need this stored in a variable, you'll have to define it outside of this function and assign it within the `done` function.